# Best way get complex sql data(Performance issue)

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

Hi i have a timeLogs table having with columns(id,startTime,EndTime,User_Id,Client_Id,Project_Id,Task_Id,TotalHours)

I need output Having columns(Client,Project,Task,NoOfResources,TotalTime) with projectids,taskids,datefrom ,datetill filters Sample output and table structure are shown below

[image]

Here User_Id ,Client_Id,Task_Id,Project_Id are foreign keys with users,clients,tasks,projects

Here # of resources is user count

I am doing it through a stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetProjectUtilizationReport] 
    (@DateFrom datetime =null,
     @DateTill datetime = null, 
     @TaskTypeIds nvarchar(max) = null,
     @TaskIds nvarchar(max) = null,
     @UserIds  nvarchar(max) = null,
     @ProjectIds  nvarchar(max) = null)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable(id int,
                            ProjectId int,
                            ClientId int,
                            UserId int,
                            TaskId int,
                            TotalHours numeric(18,2),
                            StartTime datetime,
                            TaskTypeId int)

    --- create a temp table with data dump
    INSERT INTO #TempTable(Id, ProjectId, ClientId, UserId, TaskId, TotalHours, StartTime, TaskTypeId) 
        SELECT 
            tl.id,Project_Id, Client_Id,
            User_Id, Task_Id, TotalHours,
            StartTime, TaskType_Id 
        FROM 
            TimeLogs tl 
        JOIN 
            Tasks t ON tl.Task_Id = t.Id

    --apply filter to temp table
    IF (@DateFrom IS NOT NULL)
        DELETE FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE StartTime < @DateFrom

    IF (@DateTill IS NOT NULL)
        DELETE FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE StartTime > @DateTill

    IF (@TaskTypeIds IS NOT NULL)
        DELETE FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE TaskTypeId NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@TaskTypeIds, ','))

    IF (@TaskIds IS NOT NULL)
        DELETE FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE TaskId NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@TaskIds, ','))

    IF (@UserIds IS NOT NULL)
        DELETE FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@UserIds, ','))

    IF (@ProjectIds IS NOT NULL)
        DELETE FROM #TempTable 
        WHERE ProjectId NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@ProjectIds, ','))

    --finaly select data
    SELECT 
        p.Name as Project, c.Name as Client,
        tl.TaskId, t.Name as Task,
        SUM(TotalHours) as Totalhours,
        COUNT(DISTINCT tl.UserId) as NoOfResources,
        c.Id as ClientId 
    FROM
        #TempTable tl
    JOIN
        Tasks t ON tl.TaskId = t.Id 
    JOIN
        Clients c ON c.Id = tl.ClientId
    JOIN
        Projects p ON tl.ProjectId = p.Id 
    GROUP BY
        tl.TaskId, c.id, c.Name, p.Name, t.Name 

    --drop temp table 
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

I think there may be a much better approach - something like an view etc but I don't have any ideas.

May to put data in other table on insert etc.

Please put your suggestion show that i can get results as fast as posible.

Comment: You have provided the expected result. But there is no sample data.

Comment: Hi i have attached a different screen shot also column with _ are foreign keys

Comment: Can you believe that people in SO provide you solution without proper sample data? We do not know for which `Client_Id` does `Nokia` belongs to in your table data. Also provide sample data as text instead of image, since it will be easy for us to prepare sample data and try to solve problem for you.

Comment: @Viki888 I have attached new pic with sample data and out put required

Answer (score 2):

I often try to avoid #tables where I can.

```
SELECT  c.Name AS Client, p.Name AS Project, t.Name AS Task, COUNT(DISTINCT tl.User_Id) AS NoOfResources, SUM(TotalHours) AS Totalhours         
FROM TimeLogs tl
INNER JOIN Tasks t ON tl.Task_Id =t.Id 
INNER JOIN Clients c ON c.Id =tl.Client_Id
INNER JOIN Projects p ON tl.Project_Id =p.Id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(ISNULL(@UserIds, ''), ',')) users ON users.Item = tl.User_Id OR @UserIds IS NULL
INNER JOIN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(ISNULL(@TaskTypeIds, ''), ',')) tasktypes ON tasktypes.Item = tl.TaskType_Id OR @TaskTypeIds IS NULL
INNER JOIN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(ISNULL(@TaskIds, ''), ',')) tasks ON tasks.Item = tl.Task_Id OR @TaskIds IS NULL
INNER JOIN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(ISNULL(@ProjectIds, ''), ',')) projects ON projects.Item = tl.Project_Id OR @ProjectIds IS NULL
WHERE (@DateFrom IS NULL OR StartTime < @DateFrom)
AND (@DateTill IS NULL OR StartTime > @DateTill)
GROUP BY c.Id, c.Name, p,Id, p.Name, t.Id, t.Name
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen that works great in fact much batter then me but what about performance in case of large data assume millions of record in that table

Comment: @jitender you can test it. but I have found that #tables are resource intensive

Comment: Yes i am agree with you in this case but i am not so strong in sql  and your solution will give me much batter performance still i thinks there may be some batter performance solution

Comment: @jitender execute both queries, check the execution plan, and compare

Comment: @jitender glad it helped.

Comment: @jitender just FYI, it is always better to mark the answer, so the question doesn't appear on the unanswered list.

Comment: its batter but not the best .That's why i didn't mark it as answer